# Text processing on CSV file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

I am dealing with a file which has the following form:

```
"1999-01-04";1391.12;3034.53;66.515625;86.2;441.39
"1999-01-05";1404.86;3072.41;66.3125;86.17;440.63
"1999-01-06";1435.12;3156.59;66.4375;86.32;441
```

Sometimes, there are values with no decimals (e.g. 441 instead of 441.0) and I need the decimals to be there. How do I write a script such that all integers are added .0 so that they become floats?

Comment: I know, this is not the answer to the question, since you asked for a bash based solution. Anyway, why don't you use the `csv` module of python for that?

Comment: If you know that the number of input fields is six, you could just aim low and go with `awk -F\; '{ printf "%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%.2f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6 }'`.

Comment: Two reasons basically: 1) I know little about Python, 2) the little I know (if it is accurate) tells me bash is a lot faster than Python. Hence, I am more interested in learning how to do it in bash so that I can use this knowledge to deal with big files at a smaller cost. Makes sense?

Comment: @Alexandre Python is significantly faster than bash for text processing, although both awk and sed are generally quicker than python(for text processing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With sed

```
sed 's/\(;[^\.]*\)\(;\|$\)/\1.00\2/g' file
```

just a simple replacement regex.

```
"1999-01-04";1391.12;3034.53;66.515625;86.2;441.39
"1999-01-05";1404.86;3072.41;66.3125;86.17;440.63
"1999-01-06";1435.12;3156.59;66.4375;86.32;441.00
```

Comment: `^1` but IMHO it's clearer if you add  `-r` and get rid of all of the escaping to activate ERE metachars: `sed -r 's/(;[^\.]*)(;|$)/\1.00\2/g' file`

Answer (score 2):

Save this `awk` script as *awk.src*:

```
BEGIN {
  FS=";"
}
#
## MAIN Block
#
{
  printf $1; printf FS;
  for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
    if ($i !~ "\\.") {
      printf "%.1f", $i;
    }
    else { printf $i; }
    if (i!=NF) {
      printf FS;
    }
    else { printf "\n"; }
  }
}
```

Try it:

```
$ awk -f awk.src < sample.txt 
"1999-01-04";1391.12;3034.53;66.515625;86.2;441.39
"1999-01-05";1404.86;3072.41;66.3125;86.17;440.63
"1999-01-06";1435.12;3156.59;66.4375;86.32;441.0
```