# Concatenating characters on each field of CSV file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

I am dealing with a CSV file which has the following form:

```
Dates;A;B;C;D;E
"1999-01-04";1391.12;3034.53;66.515625;86.2;441.39
"1999-01-05";1404.86;3072.41;66.3125;86.17;440.63
"1999-01-06";1435.12;3156.59;66.4375;86.32;441
```

Since the BLAS routine I need to implement on such data takes double-floats only, I guess the easiest way is to concatenate d0 at the end of each field, so that each line looks like:

```
"1999-01-04";1391.12d0;3034.53d0;66.515625d0;86.2d0;441.39d0
```

In pseudo-code, that would be:

```
For every line except the first line
    For every field except the first field
      Substitute ; with d0; and Substitute newline with d0 newline
```

My imagination suggests me it should be something like

cat file.csv | awk -F; 'NR>1 & NF>1'{print line} | sed 's/;/d0\n/g' | sed 's/\n/d0\n/g'

Any input?

Comment: something like `cat big-prices.csv 1>output.txt; tail -n +2 big-prices.csv | sed 's/;/d0/g' | sed 's/$/d0/g' 1>>output.txt;`

Comment: Why not just tweak the sed answer you accepted previously: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31068327/1745001?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR>1 {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i"d0"} 1' file
Dates;A;B;C;D;E
"1999-01-04";1391.12d0;3034.53d0;66.515625d0;86.2d0;441.39d0
"1999-01-05";1404.86d0;3072.41d0;66.3125d0;86.17d0;440.63d0
"1999-01-06";1435.12d0;3156.59d0;66.4375d0;86.32d0;441d0
```

That is, set the field separator to `;`. Starting on line 2, loop through all the fields from the 2nd one appending `d0`. Then, use `1` to print the line.

Comment: This would not work when the first column contains a `;`. I would use the `FPATH` variable:  `awk 'NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i"d0"}}1' OFS=\; FPAT='("[^"]+")|([^;]+)'`

Comment: @hek2mgl It seems to be a `;`-separated file, so I don't think a `;` would appear. Anyway, your suggestion with `FPAT` seems to be quite cool, it reminds me that I have to learn how to use it : )

Comment: The CSV format used here is a bit weird. Since the first field is enclosed in `""` it looks like that the quotes were used to allow the `;` in the first field. Probably I'm thinking too much from it...

Answer (score 3):

Could use this sed

```
sed '1!{s/\(;[^;]*\)/\1d0/g}' file
```

Skips the first line then replaces each field beginning with `;`(skipping the first) with itself and `d0`.

#### Output

```
Dates;A;B;C;D;E
"1999-01-04";1391.12d0;3034.53d0;66.515625d0;86.2d0;441.39d0
"1999-01-05";1404.86d0;3072.41d0;66.3125d0;86.17d0;440.63d0
"1999-01-06";1435.12d0;3156.59d0;66.4375d0;86.32d0;441d0
```

Comment: The answer is actually wrong. Please try to add a `;` into the first field of the input data.

Comment: @hek2mgl All the others would fail if you did that as well, even the accepted one. It is highly unlikely that there will be an embedded `;` in the date.

Comment: I'm about to add a hint below `fedors` answer and suggest `awk 'NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i"d0"}}1' OFS=\; FPAT='("[^"]+")|([^;]+)' a.txt` which would work.

Comment: The requirement clearly and explicitly states: `For every field except the first field Substitute ; with d0`. It does not state: `Add a d0` to every field. I'm wondering how the OP could overlook this when accepting the answer.

Comment: Why don't the two of you create a chatroom and workout the differences from there or move the complete discussion to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298214/can-someone-confirm-if-i-am-missing-something-and-this-answer-is-valid), not only one-side of it....

Answer (score 2):

Your data format looks a bit weird. Enclosing the first column in double quotes makes me think that it can contain the delimiter, the semicolon, itself. However, I don't know the application which produces that data but if this is the case, then you can use the following GNU awk command:

```
awk 'NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i"d0"}}1' OFS=\; FPAT='("[^"]+")|([^;]+)' file
```

The key here is the FPAT variable. Using it use are able to define how a field can look like instead of being limited to specify a set of field delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

**big-prices.csv**

```
Dates;A;B;C;D;E
"1999-01-04";1391.12;3034.53;66.515625;86.2;441.39
"1999-01-05";1404.86;3072.41;66.3125;86.17;440.63
"1999-01-06";1435.12;3156.59;66.4375;86.32;441
```

**preprocess script**

```
head -n 1 big-prices.csv 1>output.txt; \
tail -n +2 big-prices.csv | \
  sed 's/;/d0;/g' | \
  sed 's/$/d0/g' | \
  sed 's/"d0/"/g' 1>>output.txt;
```

**output.txt**

```
Dates;A;B;C;D;E
"1999-01-04";1391.12d0;3034.53d0;66.515625d0;86.2d0;441.39d0
"1999-01-05";1404.86d0;3072.41d0;66.3125d0;86.17d0;440.63d0
"1999-01-06";1435.12d0;3156.59d0;66.4375d0;86.32d0;441d0
```

note: would have to make minor modification to second sed if file has trailing whitespaces at end of lines..

Comment: The answer is actually wrong. Please try to add a ; into the first field of the input data

Comment: not wrong - user has not specified in his requirements the possibility of semicolons in the string delimeted Date field.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

**Input**

```
$ cat file
Dates;A;B;C;D;E
"1999-01-04";1391.12;3034.53;66.515625;86.2;441.39
"1999-01-05";1404.86;3072.41;66.3125;86.17;440.63
"1999-01-06";1435.12;3156.59;66.4375;86.32;441
```

**gsub** (any awk)

```
$ awk 'FNR>1{ gsub(/;[^;]*/,"&d0")}1' file
Dates;A;B;C;D;E
"1999-01-04";1391.12d0;3034.53d0;66.515625d0;86.2d0;441.39d0
"1999-01-05";1404.86d0;3072.41d0;66.3125d0;86.17d0;440.63d0
"1999-01-06";1435.12d0;3156.59d0;66.4375d0;86.32d0;441d0
```

**gensub** (gawk)

```
$ awk 'FNR>1{ print gensub(/(;[^;]*)/,"\\1d0","g"); next }1' file
Dates;A;B;C;D;E
"1999-01-04";1391.12d0;3034.53d0;66.515625d0;86.2d0;441.39d0
"1999-01-05";1404.86d0;3072.41d0;66.3125d0;86.17d0;440.63d0
"1999-01-06";1435.12d0;3156.59d0;66.4375d0;86.32d0;441d0
```